# Kibana Unable to connect to ES

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana-4

[image]

I am running a ELK stack , ES is on the same machine as of the kibana. Kibana was working fine, but then crashed with the error.

Please help me out

Comment: Are you sure your ES cluster is still up? What do you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200` from that host?

Comment: yes it is.. 
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Demo Stack",
  "cluster_name" : "qa_ELK_stack",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.4.4",
    "build_hash" : "c88f77ffc81301dfa9dfd81ca2232f09588bd512",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-02-19T13:05:36Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.3"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

Comment: Hi Nishant , Consider upvoting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
verify_ssl: false
```

here is the reference link 
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-unable-to-connect-to-elasticsearch-at-http-localhost-9200/29865

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
verify_ssl: false
```

in kibana.yml & restart the Kibana